# Passing a string translation to quail-defrule

Tags: quail

I don't understand how this is to be used:

```
(quail-defrule ",q" "abcd")
```

After evaluating this, and typing `,q`, I get an underscored `a`: but
how am I supposed to select one of the other characters?  Doing
`(quail-next-translation)` does start going through them, but only
after inserting an `a`.

Comment: I've no idea how quail works. But how would you select between `abc` and `xyz` if you did `(quail-defrule ",q" ["abc" "xyz"])`? From the docstring, it sounds like the same sort of choice.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(quail-defrule ",q" ["abcd"])
```

Comment: It would help if you would elaborate, e.g., explain why/how this corrects the mistake.

Comment: Yeah, I know the function takes a vector argument too, I was just curious about how the string argument is supposed to be used.